# Animating :before element on hover

Tags: html, css

Trying to have my back and next buttons have an animated 'background' created by a :before element when hovered over. The back and next buttons are located at the sides of the page and are the text of the posts so I don't have full control over their content. I want the background block to stretch from one side to the other (right to left on next, left to right on previous) behind the text.

I want the background block (:before element) to be the full height and width of the text it is behind (text has padding)

css (I left out the transition: css until I can get it working properly.)

```css
#nav-BN {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 50px 0;
}

.nav-previous, .nav-next { 
  display: block; 
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav-previous { left: 0; }
.nav-next { right: 0; }

.nav-previous a, .nav-next a { 
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.nav-previous a:before, .nav-next a:before { 
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0; top: 0;
  height: 100%; width: 0%;
  background-color: #000;
}

.nav-previous a:hover:before, .nav-next a:hover:before { width: 100%; }

.nav-previous:before { transform-origin: left center; }
.nav-next:before { transform-origin: right center; }
```

```html
<div id="nav-BN">
   <div class="nav-previous">
      <a>link</a>
   </div>

   <div class="nav-next">
      <a>link</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Issues I've encountered is using 100% width, makes it full width of screen not of the containing div. text jumping around page when hovered, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this before and I think it is exactly what you are looking for: 
http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/

Use the example hvr-shutter-out-horizontal :

`<a class="hvr-shutter-out-horizontal" href="#">Shutter Out Horizontal</a>`

but change the css for .hvr-shutter-out-horizontal to background: transparent;

Answer (score 1):

https://cssanimation.rocks/pseudo-elements/

Hope this helps. Not sure exactly what you are trying to do-

Comment: Essentially create an animating background. Text on a black box, but the black box doesn't show until you hover over the text, and it shows by stretching from one side to another

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try

> flex box

Comment: How would flex-box solve my issue? I am using flexbox in my site already